# Are there any alternatives to Livestream and Justin.tv when it comes to streaming games?

Tags: pc, streaming

Are there any alternative to Livestream and Justin.tv when it comes to streaming game footage from your PC? I currently use Livestream and it is a pretty good service, I'm just wondering if there are other alternatives that I can evaluate before I settle on one.

I'm looking to embed the stream (or multiple streams if I can) in my website so something that would be geared towards that would be greatly appreciated. the result doesn't have to be an online service either, if it is a program to run on your PC and it sends the video to your site somehow that would be fine as well (ex. something like fraps on it streams instead of just recording)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never used one by you should definitely check out this site:

http://www.ustream.tv

A lot of gamers use this to broadcast their LPs or matches. (e.g: Husky and HDStracraft streamed the HDH Tournament on UStream)

Answer (score 4):

The past year has seen an increase in the popularity of own3D as a broadcast service, particularly it seems amongst Quake broadcasters:

http://www.own3d.tv/

The reasons for the switch have included high video quality and a single ad that plays at the start of the stream (with no further interruptions).

I unfortunately can't speak to the ease of use at the production side since I'm not a broadcaster.

Comment: Own3d is no longer a streaming service

Answer (score 2):

The guys at #quakelive also suggest [SopCast](http://www.sopcast.com/). Basically, it's P2P streaming.