# How do I live-stream games?

Tags: streaming

I want to live-stream some games while I play them. How do I do this? What are the requirements and steps?

Comment: What do you mean by "stream some games while I play them"?

Comment: You might consider checking out [this existing question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/are-there-any-alternative-to-livestream-and-justin-tv-when-it-comes-to-streaming), to see if its info might help you.

Comment: Theres no point in telling us what you're using; its not relevant to the question. If someone recommended OBS, I'd say accept that answer.

Comment: Yes, there is a point. Nobody mentions it, but me. It is relevant to the questions because it a software that falls into my question.

Comment: It has no relevance to your question. If anything, it is an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest streaming with the no longer free program, [XSplit](http://www.xsplit.com). It's very popular for StarCraft II, and is quite easy to use. It can stream both your game audio and your microphone. (Plus, it doesn't need your Stereo Mix!) You can mix together scenes which you can switch between at any time. Plus, it streams straight to the website, and you don't have to have the website you are streaming to open.

Works well with twitch.tv and ustream.com

Comment: @skfd It isn't free...

Comment: @Kecoey It's free to use but feature-locked.

Answer (score 4):

**How to do this:**

1. [VH Screen capture drivers](http://www.splitmedialabs.com/vh-video-sdk/vh-screen-capture) to
   capture what your doing on screen. (Recently bought by XSplit)
2. Make certain audio drivers are up to date. And are not using Windows default drivers.
3. Check to make certain Mic and "Stereo Mixer" are not hidden, active and working correctly
4. Download [Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) to actually stream video/audio
5. Streaming sites will offer you a Streaming API key or an XML file that contains the streaming key. Plug it into the Adobe Software

If all goes well, you should be set to go.

**Alternative Programs:**

- [WebcamMax](http://www.webcammax.com/) - $50
- [Broadcam](http://www.nchsoftware.com/broadcam/index.html) - Trial / $50
- [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) - Free / open source
- [XSplit](http://xsplit.com) - Free / Beta

**Streaming Websites:**

- [www.UStream.tv](http://www.UStream.tv) - Free / Ads
- [www.twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv) - Free / Ads
- [www.livestream.com](http://www.livestream.com) - Free / Ads
- [www.bitgravity.com](http://bitgravity.com/) - Subscription

For more applications and a great guide that goes into a lot more detail from the [Team Liquid Forums](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=124256).

Comment: Please include http://obsproject.com/. It is a free program that works like XSplit and is currently in Beta, but works pretty well. I use it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Close friend of mine has been using [Dyyno](http://www.dyyno.com) with fairly good results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [D3DGear](http://www.d3dgear.com), a broadcasting software that works perfectly for video game.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit 2015-09-12: By now I'm only using [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/). It does everything I want and then some.

Moved from edit to question

Answer (score -2):

I also used D3DGear http://www.d3dgear.com/fraps-alternative, it is very good.

Comment: Generally, if you're going to recommend a product to achieve a goal, you need to do more than give us a link to the product.  You have to tell us HOW to use said product to achieve the goal.  Without that, this is not at all useful.